# android studio surround find results with if statement

Tags: android, android-studio, refactoring, automated-refactoring

Is there a way of surrounding search results in android studio with a predefined if statement?

Like every Log.d line

```
Log.d("foo","bar");
```

surrounded with an if statement? Or any other statment.

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
    Log.d("foo","bar");
}
```

Comment: You can use find and replace option.

Comment: But how can I keep the original line? Is there a way to automate it?

Comment: find: Log.d("foo","bar");

replace:
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
    Log.d("foo","bar");
}

if you want to find just "Log.d", you have to use regular expression.

Comment: Can you give me some examples? I want to surround every Log.d line.

Comment: (Log\.d\(\w*\);) is find every Log.d line but what should you write in replace area? I'm stuck :)

Answer (score 2):

Select your line, press (in win) **Ctrl+Alt+T** and select "if". See http://www.developerphil.com/android-studio-tips-of-the-day-roundup-2/

Comment: yes, but is there a way to do it more than one time? I have like 100 log.d's scattered along the source.

Comment: ou.. so in this case use Ctrl+Shift+R - for replacing text in whole project/module and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with regex replacement.

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+R
2. In the options tab, make sure the regex checkbox is selected and scope is Whole project.

Text to find:

```
(Log\.d.*\;)
```

Replace with:

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){$1}
```